# AngularJS: ng-switchs removed data from input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I have a Laravel application and I want to add users an schools through wizards. I have made a very simple wizard with AngularJS.

```
$scope.addSchool = {
    items : [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    current : 1,
    progress : 0
}

$scope.addSchoolNext = function(next)
{
    $scope.addSchool.current = next;
    $scope.addSchool.progress = (100 / $scope.addSchool.items.length) * ($scope.addSchool.current - 1);
}

$scope.addSchoolPrevious = function(previous)
{
    $scope.addSchool.current = previous;
    $scope.addSchool.progress = (100 / $scope.addSchool.items.length) * ($scope.addSchool.current - 1);
}
```

I have ng-switch in my view:

```
 <div class="create-school-wizard" ng-switch on="addSchool.current">
      <section class="create-school-wizard-1" ng-switch-when="1">
           Add data
           <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSchoolNext(2)">Next</button>
       </section>
       <section class="create-school-wizard-2" ng-switch-when="2">
            Add data
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSchoolPrevious(1)">Previous</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSchoolNext(2)">Next</button>
       </section>
       <section class="create-school-wizard-3" ng-switch-when="3">
            Add data
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSchoolPrevious(2)">Previous</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </section>
 </div>
```

It works fine! I have just one problem. When I go the the next page and then go back, the input fields are empty. Actually, I dont want to save my inputy data in AngularJS models because of, Laravel takes care for posting and saving the data.

I also tried ng-show, but ng-show submits the entire form when I click on next.

Comment: your input data will not be "saved" in angular models, it will be loaded into them when the page loads. the only other way is to use value={{myValue}} on the inputs. BTW, you dont show any inputs in your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't have a plunker, I created a different one. What happens when you go back and forth between pages, scopes get destoryed, so you need to repopulate the data when it loads.

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/laSUM6RDcF4SeTzMSCIu?p=preview

```
  <div ng-switch on="someVariableToSwitchOn">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
      <input ng-model="data.value" />
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <input ng-model="data.value" placeholder="Not prepopulated" ng-change="onChange()"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input ng-model="data.prepopulated"/>
```

In this example you see that I can set the ng-model on an input and it will be tied to my scope variables.

My JS is a bit overly complex, but the basics are understandable. When the page loads I create $scope.data. it is not initialized so the first input will not switch. Once the user types "blue" into the first input, it will switch and do the other input will not run the change function.

If I want to prepopulate some input, then I have to do that as the page loads, so that it's done in a timely manner.

```
  $scope.someVariableToSwitchOn = false;
  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.onChange = function(){
    if($scope.data.value === 'blue'){
      $scope.someVariableToSwitchOn = true;
      console.log('switched');
    } else {
      $scope.someVariableToSwitchOn = false; 
    }
  };

  $scope.data.prepopulated = "prepopulated";
```

You can prepopulate these fields in a manner of ways, you can get data using $http from your server, or you can persist the data with localStorage in your browser (if you're just moving between pages and not relying on a server to save this (search for ng-localstorage) )